# running sencha touch apps in emulators under osx/linux

Tags: linux, macos, cordova, extjs

I'm trying to test Sencha Touch with phonegap under OSX 10.10.1.

I have android-sdk-manager installed and on the PATH with latest android sdk installed.

I created a nexus 7 emulator running android.

I started the android emulator and the IOS emulator from xcode.

I created a new Sencha project by running the following command:

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/sdk generate app MyAlcoholist MyAlcoholist
```

then I enabled phonegap using the following command:

```
sencha phonegap init com.tuxin.MyAlcoholist
```

then I started the app using the following command:

```
sencha app build -run native
```

the last line of output:

```
[INF] [Phonegap] Attempting PhoneGap local run for ios android
```

i don't see any error but the application is not being deployed and executed on any of the emulators.

I configured "android ios" in app.json

any ideas?

## update

I also have gentoo linux at work, there i only configured android as the platform
and the results are the same. i see the `Attempting Phonegap local run for android`
and then nothing.

Comment: Do you have the npm package "ios-sim" installed? I think the PhoneGap/Cordova CLIs need that to launch the simulator, yet they don't auto-install it.

Comment: these sloves the ios problem. in android i needed to install version 19 sdk. ran the sencha with -d (Debug) flag and noticed the errors